# Find files that contain a string and do not contain another

Tags: text-processing, grep, text

Say, I have some files, and I want to find the files among them which contain a string but do not contain another.

grep being line based, conditions such as `grep -q printf file && grep -vq '#include <stdio.h>' file` will not work.

How should I go about doing this?

(I am on Debian, so answers specifically targeted at GNU versions of tools are fine.)

Comment: I'd look at something along the lines of a `grep -r ... --null ... wanted-str` piped to "xargs --null grep -v unwanted-str" (assuming GNU grep & xargs, for the null support)

Comment: `grep being line based, conditions such as grep -q printf file && grep -vq '#include <stdio.h>' file will not work`  While grep is line matching tool, it supports regular expressions for matching specific words and patterns. It really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: `grep -L` to get files that do not contain a match. You can also add `-q`: `-q` is line based `-L` is file based.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -vl` would report the name of the files that have at least one line that match the pattern. Here you want the files where none of the line match the pattern. GNU `grep` (as found on Debian) has a `-L` option for that:

```
grep -rlZ printf . | xargs -r0 grep -FL '#include <stdio.h>'
```

With any POSIX `grep`, you could just negate `grep -q`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q printf {} \; \
               ! -exec grep -Fq '#include <stdio.h>' {} \; \
               -print
```

A lot less efficient as that means running one to two `grep` instances on every regular file.

Comment: if there was a better more thoroughly explanation of all the flags and syntax used here it would have been easier for me to use it in my own use case :-/

Comment: @EladKatz, you'll find those in `info grep` and `info find`.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `find` with `bash -c` instead of a script.  We take file path and store it into `file` variable, then pass it further to other commands. First `grep -q` will check if there is one word/pattern that you want is present. Using its exit status, `&&` will pass it on to  second `grep -q`. If that command doesn't find a match, that means the string is not found, thus using its exit status , we pass it on to `echo` via `||` operator.

In the example below, only `file2.txt` contains `abra` but not `cadabra` word.

```
$ find -type f -exec bash -c 'file="$@";grep -q "abra" "$file"  &&  grep -q "cadabra" "$file" || echo "$file" ' sh "{}" >
./file2.txt
$ ls                                                                                                                     
file1.txt  file2.txt  file 3.txt
$ cat file1.txt
abra cadabra
$ cat file2.txt                                                                                                          
abra
$ cat file\ 3.txt                                                                                                        
abra cadabra
```

Comment: `grep -vl` returns the files that contain at least one line that doesn't match the pattern, not the files where none of the lines match the pattern.

Comment: you need `-L` not `-vl`

Comment: Stephane is correct. I switched to using `grep`'s exit status, so there's no longer `grep -vl`.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy:

```
for fname in ./*.c; do
  if grep -q -F "printf" "$fname" && ! grep -q -F "#include <stdio.h>" "$fname"; then
     printf 'File "%s" needs to include stdio.h\n' "$fname"
  fi
done
```

This will look through all C source files in the current directory and report any file that uses `printf()` without including the `stdio.h` header.

The header may be included indirectly though, so to avoid false positives, you *could* pass the code through the C preprocessor and look for the header in the preprocessed output (this seems to work with `gcc` and `clang`):

```
for fname in ./*.c; do
  if grep -q -F "printf" "$fname" && cc -E "$fname" | ! grep -q "^#.*stdio\.h\""; then
     printf 'File "%s" needs to include stdio.h\n' "$fname"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read the requirement correctly you want all files matching `$PAT_INCL` minus the files matching `$PAT_EXCL`.

Conceptually this is just set subtraction. There's not a very good standard utility for set operations in unix, but `comm` works.

```
comm -23 <(grep --files-with-match "$PAT_INCL"  * | sort) \
         <(grep --files-with-match "$PATH_EXCL" * | sort)
```

This can be made a bit more efficient by only grepping through the matching files in the second grep:

```
# Assuming filenames without whitespace
grep --files-with-match "$PAT_INCL" * | sort > incl_files
grep --files-with-match "$PAT_EXCL" $(cat incl_files) | sort > excl_files
comm -23 incl_files excl_files
```