# Find with two grep (contains AND not contains) and one awk

Tags: awk, grep, find

I would like to store in file all path files with a specific extract of file content where file contains `AAA` but NOT `BBB`.

I tried so many things but this try is close to my goal :

```
find /data/my_project -type f -name "*.php" -exec grep -q "AAA" {} \; -exec grep -L "BBB" {} \; -exec awk '/AAA/{print $NF}'> /tmp/tables_names.txt {} \;  -print > /tmp/class_list.txt
```

But... Result contains file with sometimes `AAA` only, `AAA` AND `BBB`..

**EDIT :**

This is pretty same question as [Find files that contain a string and do not contain another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337803/find-files-that-contain-a-string-and-do-not-contain-another) but where there's no answer validated it was really difficult to read.
75 % of my answer was in fact there sorry... 
But, I would like to return not only matched files paths but an extract (piece of text) of this matched file !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to find all files that contains `AAA` but no files that contain `BBB` (even if they contain `AAA`). What would you want to do with them? I'm confused by your `awk` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding all regular files with filenames matching `*.php` in or below `/data/my_project` that contain `AAA` but not `BBB` and storing their pathnames in `/tmp/class_list.txt`:

```
find /data/my_project -type f -name '*.php' \
    -exec grep -qF 'AAA' {} ';' \
    ! -exec grep -qF 'BBB' {} ';' \
    -print >/tmp/class_list.txt
```

Comment: @kusalanada : I would like to extract some word just after `AAA` in fact because I have something like `AAA = xxx;` and I want to provide a list with xxx and file path to know for wich AAA `BBB` part is missing !

Comment: Finally I used this `find /data/my_project -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -qF 'const TABLE_NAME' {} ';' ! -exec grep -qF 'BBB' {} ';' -exec awk '/const TABLE_NAME/{print $NF}' {} ';' -print >/tmp/class_list.txt` where `AAA` is in reality `const TABLE_NAME` :)

Answer (score 2):

**`find`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
find /data/my_project -type f -name "*.php" -exec \
awk '/AAA/{ a=1 }/BBB/{ b=1 }END{ exit (!a || (a && b)) }' {} \; -print > /tmp/class_list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
find /data/my_project -type f -name '*.php' -exec \
bash -c 'grep -q AAA "$1" && ! grep -q BBB "$1" && echo "$1"' -- {} \; \
> /tmp/class_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find .... -name '*.php' \
   -exec awk -v RS="\0" '/AAA/ && !/BBB/{print FILENAME}' {} \; >  out
```